# Requirements for closed, open, and short circuits

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, current, short-circuit

In terms of understanding paths in a circuit, let's take a few example circuits:

(1) Would the following circuit be considered closed or open (or something else) since it doesn't have a voltage source?

[image]

What are the requirements for a circuit to be closed? Is it that there needs to be both a voltage source and ground with a connection between the two, or something else?

(2) For short-circuits, for example:

[image]

When is a circuit considered shorted vs not? For example, what if it is a voltage_source+capacitor? what if it is a voltage_source+led? Do all components (minus a direct wire connection) added between a voltage source and ground make it a non-short circuit? Or, what are the requirements for a short circuit? (The concept I have in my head is a closed circuit with a too-high current.)

Comment: You need to define "open" and "closed" for us. You are off on a tangent of your own making, so you are responsible for the meaning of words, too. Start a dictionary? In the meantime, your last picture is physically impossible. Conduction band electrons in a metal solid are guaranteed to have no net electric field. It's a given, once steady state is reached. By physics. The mobile charges will automatically re-arrange themselves in just such a way that the net electric field is zero at every location within it (at a large enough scale -- when at subatomic scales the argument is different.)

Comment: @jonk -- I mean in its current usage, for example coming across it on https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-1/resistance/: `A short circuit is an electric circuit offering little or no resistance to the flow of current.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question and pictures don't make a whole lot of sense. These terms do not apply to circuits in the general case.

An "open circuit" is a circuit or portion of a circuit in which there is no path for current to flow. An open switch is one in the "off" position. The impedance may not truly be infinite. But it is much higher than desired. High enough that any current flow is insignificant for practical purposes.

Generally, "closed" can refer to a switch in the "on" position, or a switching transistor when it is conducting current readily. "Closed circuit" is a special term applying to a type of video system.

A "short circuit" is usually an erroneous or unintentional connection that allows current to flow around or in parallel with the desired current path. The impedance of a short circuit is not necessarily zero, but it is generally much lower than intended, thereby causing some sort of malfunction.

Sometimes a "short circuit" may be deliberately applied for test purposes. For example, it is good to test batteries by short circuiting them to make sure that no hazardous condition arises for the end user. The test would be done with precautions in place to avoid injury and property damage. It is not something people should do if they are unfamiliar with the dangers.